# Reading from variable in Perl

Tags: perl, variables, input

I have a lot of lines stored in a single variable in Perl.

I would like to know if it is possible to read those lines using <> operator.

Answer (score 14):

If you really must, you can open a filehandle to it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $lines = "one\ntwo\nthree";
open my $fh, "<", \$lines;

while( <$fh> ) { 
    print "line $.: $_";
}
```

Alternatively, if you've already got the stuff in memory anyway, you could just split it into an array:

```
my @lines = split /\n/, $lines;   # or whatever
foreach my $line( @lines ) { 
    # do stuff
}
```

That would probably be easier to read and maintain down the line.

Comment: A possible reason to do this is the trick of `open ARGV, '<', \$default_data unless @ARGV` then reading `<>` will use the default data unless files are passed in.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  As documented in [`perldoc -f open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), you can open filehandles to scalar variables.

```perl
my $data = <<'';
line1
line2
line3

open my $fh, '<', \$data;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    print "[[ $_ ]]\n";
}

# prints
# [[ line1 ]]
# [[ line2 ]]
# [[ line3 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful alternative, 
it does not use <> but works as if it did

```
for (split /^/, $lines) {
   ...
}
```

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=745018